# what does pos_label in f1_score really mean?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying out k_fold cross-validation in sklearn, and am confused by the pos_label parameter in the f1_score. I understand that the pos_label parameter has something to do with how to treat the data if the categories are other than binary. But I don't really have a good conceptual understanding of it's significance- does anyone have a good explanation of what it means on a conceptual level?

I have read the docs, and they didn't really help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The f1 score is the [harmonic mean of precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score). As such, you need to compute [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_.28classification_context.29) to compute the f1-score. Both these measures are computed in reference to "true positives" (positive instances assigned a positive label), "false positives" (negative instances assigned a positive label), etc.

The `pos_label` parameter lets you specify which class should be considered "positive" for the sake of this computation.

More concretely, imagine you're trying to build a classifier that finds some rare events within a large background of uninteresting events. In general all you care about is how well you can identify these rare results; the background labels are not otherwise intrinsically interesting. In this case you would set `pos_label` to be your interesting class. If you're in a situation where you care about the results of *all* classes, `f1_score` is probably not the appropriate metric.

Comment: Ok, so I'm actually in a multi class problem, where I'm interested in the accuracy of all classifications equally. What would you recommend to validate that? Am I completely off by using k-fold cross validation in the first place?

Comment: You could try to find the precision/recall/F1 of each class individually, if that's interesting. But jakevdp's right that using a single f1 score value for all classes is not particularly useful.

Comment: K-fold cross-validation is fine, but in the multiclass case where all classes are important, the accuracy score is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Great, thank you! For the record, I found the pandas_confusion module really useful in this - it provides a confusion matrix implemented in pandas, which is much easier to use than the one in sklearn, and it proves the accuracy score as well.